# React break .map() in condition rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I use `break` to break a `.map()` function when condition rendering is true ?

This is my example code

```
  {messages.length >= 1 ? (
   <div>
    {messages.reverse().map((e) => (
      e.senderName[0] == displayName[0] ? (<p>Status: {e.message}</p>) : null
    ))} 
   </div>
  ) : (<p>Status: Verifying...</p>)}
```

The problem is in `messages` array is gonna have a new message add every 60 second and I want to display a new message on my screen that has been add in every 60 second

Then I want to break `.map()` function after a new message has been add to `messages` array and display on my screen

What I want is like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0L52.jpg)

But the problem is like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us0It.jpg)

Comment: You may want to use find, instead of map ... so it returns the first matched Value

Comment: What other properties are on each _message_ (besides `senderName` and `message`)? Is there anything uniquely identifying?

Comment: In every message is something like this 
{message: 'hello 1', senderId: 'x3vbouvn', timestamp: '2022-07-15T06:22:54.482Z', topic: 'CHAT', senderName: Array(3), …}
but didn't have an uniquely identifying

Comment: How are elements added to `messages`? Perhaps you're appending when you should be setting

Comment: I use a PubSub to publish() my message to `messages`

   `const sendMessage = (message) => {publish(message, { persist: true });}; `

Comment: That's not what I asked. You have a state variable `messages`. How does it get data?

Comment: Oh sorry, my `messages` state is get data from a `sendMessage('you message')` function in this function it will `publish(message, { persist: true})` every 60 second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use break to stop .map() method. I see that you are trying to render messages if message belongs to current user.

I can recommend you to filter the messages first, then render the filtered array with mapping. Like:

```
const usersMessages = messages.reverse().filter((e) => (e.senderName[0] === displayName[0]);

return (
<div>
{usersMessages.length > 0 ? (usersMessages.map(e =>{
return((<p>Status: {e.message}</p>))
})) : <p>Status: Verifying...</p>)}
</div>
)
```

Of course you must have a part in your code that updates the messages array and triggers a re-render when data is updated.

Comment: Oh That great!, but I have a little bit of problem here 
can `userMessages` return once when  `(e.senderName[0] === displayName[0])` ?
becuase in `messages` there is so many element that `senderName` is the same

Comment: This is how you have been filtering. So if you need something else, you need to specify/filter what you need exactly. filter method returns the exact object when the condition matches. and if you want you can still expand your condition with filter method and/or you can chain filter methods. Like messages.filter(do something).filter(do something more). But this is up to you.

Comment: at lease I can do from you explanation, thank you so much, you save my day :)